# React & Node JS deployment on Apache server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, apache, npm

I am trying to deploy my react app with node js as a backend on apache server on a shared hosting. My folder structure is lke following:

1. client //frontend folder along with build folder inside it "created
   by npm run build"
2. config
3. controllers
4. models
5. node_modules
6. routes
7. package.json
8. package.lock.json
9. server.js

I have checked numerous tutorials and articles on the internet but failed to deploy it. Do I need to create ".htaccess" file? Can anyone guide me how to deploy it properly.

My server.js code:

```
// ROUTES
app.use("/api/sms", sms);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/client", "build", "index.html"));
});

//CONFIGURE PORT
const PORT = process.env.port || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `Server running in "${process.env.NODE_ENV}" mode on port "${PORT}"`
  )
);
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: stuck at as its not running on server, shows nothing

Comment: how are you running it on server? with node index.js cmd? or ..?